# php session are not working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

In wordpress session is not working. i want to load div on one first time of site load.

```html
 <?php session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['div_loading']))
{
   $_SESSION['div_loading'] = 1;   
?>
<div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.8; cursor: wait; position: fixed; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage" style="z-index: 1011; position: fixed; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 806px; top: 25%; left: 19.5%; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 3px solid rgb(170, 170, 170); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<div id="brewery-check">
  <h2>Please Select</h2>
  <?php echo $_SESSION['div_loading'] ;
  ?>
  <a href="/#" id="brewery-link"> 
link1  
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com" id="restaurant-link">
link2
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: "is not working" - what does it do instead?  error message, log files, description of what happens may help diagnose the problem

Answer (score 1):

please add code in `function.php`
Try this:

```
function Sessioninit() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'Sessioninit', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use cookie instead of session. In most cases (it depends of PHP settings) the session will have limited lifetime.

If you want to do this **the right way**, you can use `init` hook and setup your cookie data there. You can place that piece of code in your `functions.php` file.

```
<?php

function sw_31159775() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['your_cookie_name'])) {
        $expirity= time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        setcookie('your_cookie_name', 'some value', $expirity);
    }
}

add_action('init', 'sw_31159775');

?>
```

And then you can access `$_COOKIE['your_cookie_name']` anywhere in your code.

Comment: session is also kind of cookie :D and session do not get destroy on closing browser .. we do it explicit

Comment: Yes, they are cookies at nutshell. But you can't rely on cookies if you want specific action to be performed only for first visit.

Comment: exactly either he need to reload page or make ajax call to get data

Answer (score 0):

your session code seems fine to me, but you are accessing them just after setting them. below i am showing how session work

When you open page requested form sever you get phpsessid and with this id you store data on server by session   so you need to fetch those data .. and normally you reload/make ajax request so that you can fetch data.

```
Session id : data {some data}
```

key value pair (hash table )

so try

```
 <?php 

 if(isset($_SESSION['div_loading'])
     echo $_SESSION['div_loading'];
 else
     echo 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be first line in your current active theme's functions.php file.

```
if (!session_id())
    session_start();
```